# Specifying complete installation option when running msi from powershell

Tags: powershell, gstreamer, start-process

I am trying to automate the installation of gstreamer on windows using powershell

I have the msi file downloaded, and am installing it as shown below

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $path = "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\gstreamer-1.0-devel-mingw-x86_64-1.18.0.msi";
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $path -Argument "/qn"
```

However, this does not get me the complete installation, because it is only selecting the default arguments from the installer.

I need to specify for it to perform the complete installation, how can I modify my arguments? So that it selects "complete" installation and not "typical" like it does by default

[image]

Comment: The args are an array:  `Start -Wait $path /qb,ALLUSERS=1,INSTALLDIR=C:\DIR`  Passing double quotes is another story.

Comment: I am trying to figure out what arguments to use for it to trigger the "Complete" install

For example I've tried Complete=1 but it doesn't have any effect

Comment: Like this?  `Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $path -Argument "/qn","Complete=1"`

Comment: This might work too `Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $path -Argument "/qn Complete=1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These should work:

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $path -Argument "/qn","Complete=1"

Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $path -Argument "/qn Complete=1"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, so I ran the Installer from power shell with and without the /qn argument and logged the process into two different files. Finally, I compared the result and I was able to find that for installing process using the UI it adds a property called INSTALLLEVEL, which is set to 1000 (don't know why this value yet). So, by adding the argument INSTALLLEVEL=1000 it installs the complete version.

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath gstreamer-1.0-mingw-x86_64-1.20.2.msi -Argument "/qn INSTALLLEVEL=1000"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had tried below but it did not work

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $path -Argument "/qn","Complete=1"

Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $path -Argument "/qn Complete=1"
```

While this is working fine for me.

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath gstreamer-1.0-mingw-x86_64-1.20.2.msi -Argument "/qn INSTALLLEVEL=1000"
```